# How to define a sequalize table field which has multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am working on a project with nodejs, postgres, sequelize and express and trying to insert values to a seqaulzied database table from an API response , which contains an array of objects. API response contains the below location field.

```
"description": "Hello",
"location": [
    {
        "path": "Hekki",
        "address": "test"
    }
],
```

And I have a table mapping for this something similar to below.

```
const model = db.define('Tablename', {
    description: Sequelize.TEXT,
    location: {
         path: Sequelize.STRING,
         address: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
```

But this won't work since this is not an array definition and the syntax is also not valid.

The location field has two attributes. How should I handle this properly.

Could someone help me to write the proper table definition for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use multiple table and create association.

In other words you need to create a table called location with path and address attribute. Then you can refer it by id for the description.

### This is the only way of implementation in SQL database. It would have been easy if u were using No-Sql database.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes I did create a separate table for locations. there is no other way perhaps. :)

Comment: BTW, the JSON field can be also used.